# Access shared folder using a specific windows credential

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, impersonation

I'm currently working with a requirement: download a file from the database then write it to a shared folder. Temporarily, I'm working on a path on my local:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, content);
```

My problem is the shared folder is on a windows machine and only a specific account will be allowed to write to this folder.

Now I know the basics of `Impersonation` but I don't know if it is possible to impersonate on a Docker container on a Linux machine.

In short, I want to deploy my application on a Linux container then write a file to a windows shared folder with limited access.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder on the host or mounted on the host? If so you can then map the host folder to the container. e.g.

```
C:\> "Hello" > c:\temp\testfile.txt
C:\> docker run -v c:/temp:/tmp busybox cat /tmp/testfile.txt
```

- `c:/temp` being a local path on the host
- `/tmp` being the path in the container.

More details here: [volume-shared-filesystems](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)